# Exporting an Image from a WinForms application to PowerPoint with transparency

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, powerpoint, clipboard

I've been having trouble pasting an image from my application into PowerPoint, while preserving transparency. I have an image stored as a `System.Drawing.Graphics` type which I then convert to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` type and copy to the clipboard. During this process I also use `Bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Black)` so that everything in the original document which was black will be transparent when the image is pasted.

```
if (GraphicsInterface.getGraphics() != null)
{
    Image image = GraphicsInterface.getGraphics();
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
    bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
    Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);
}
```

However, when I try to paste the image into an application like PowerPoint, instead of being transparent, everything that was black is now a very light gray.

Is my approach correct? Is there a way to reconcile the transparent values in .net and PowerPoint? Or will the transparency have to be done manually once the image is inserted to PowerPoint?

Comment: The fact that you are using "C# and .NET" is largely irrelevant to your question. The important thing is that you are using Windows Forms.

Comment: @John: I understand why C# is irrelevant, but why is Windows Forms more relevant than .NET? I am pretty new to Windows development and I'm curious as to why that is

Comment: Windows Forms it the subset of .NET that you are using if you are using `System.Drawing`. It's a tiny subset compared to the entirety of .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue by loading a known good file with transparency. I searched around a little bit and finally was able to come up with something that got the image onto the clipboard with transparency, which I then pasted into PowerPoint 2007 successfully.

You may still need to work some magic with the `MakeTransparent()` operation, but this should get you started. Also, don't forget to dispose of the images properly. I omitted `using` statements for clarity.

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@".\Star.png");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
DataObject data = new DataObject("PNG", stream);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

Comment: Note that the "PNG" format is only supported by *Microsoft Office*.

Comment: Thanks, @AMissico. Do you mean by this that other office-like products, such as OOo.org, will not accept an image added to the clipboard in this way? (I'll not be able to confirm this at the office.)

Comment: @kbrmington: (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799442/need-help-setting-an-image-with-transparent-background-to-clipboard for reference.) From my experimentation, I believe the "PNG" clipboard format is a custom format implemented by *Microsoft Office*. I thought this was a solution to my problem but found it only works with *Microsoft Office* applications. I was able to test with Office 2003 and Office 2007. I also tested with all graphics applications on my computer and none of them understood the format. I used the "Clipboard Viewer" to monitor the clipboard while testing.

Comment: @AMissico: Thanks. I'm going to put some thought into this. What are you pasting into?

Comment: @kbrimington: I normally use *Paint Shop Pro 9*. Yet, I was trying to get the image to paste into anything. I think a good application to test with would be *Paint.NET* since it is free.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. To make the image transparent I just created a bitmap, made the necessary color transparent, and cast it back to an image.

Comment: @Patrick: I'm glad it helped. Do keep an eye on @AMissico's question (referenced in the comments) in case a more-portable solution surfaces.

Comment: @AMissico Gimp supports the PNG type too, and I suspect increasingly more apps are supporting it nowadays. For those that don't, you'll have to get into the giant mess that is the bitfields-type DIB format; a 32-bit RGB format that keeps getting abused as being ARGB.