# How to use an image as mouse pointer instead of the default arrow using C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, mouse

After browsing, I have a code to to control the movements of mouse programatically by giving the co-ordinates using C#. i want to do the same thing but mouse pointer should be replaced by a dot image. i'm not able to get it... so please let me know if there is any way in C#...

Advance Thanks:)

Comment: You need to specify if this is a Windows Forms or WPF or web application.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [great tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors) that shows you how to do that.

## UPDATE

As Hans Passant brought to my attention, there is a better approach.  Here is his version, taken from [this Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305800/using-custom-colored-cursors-in-a-c-sharp-windows-application/4306984#4306984):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;

static class NativeMethods {
    public static Cursor LoadCustomCursor(string path) {
        IntPtr hCurs = LoadCursorFromFile(path);
        if (hCurs == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
        var curs = new Cursor(hCurs);
        // Note: force the cursor to own the handle so it gets released properly
        var fi = typeof(Cursor).GetField("ownHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fi.SetValue(curs, true);
        return curs;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string path);
}
```

And here is a usage example:

```
this.Cursor = NativeMethods.LoadCustomCursor(@"c:\windows\cursors\aero_busy.ani");
```

Good luck!!

Comment: That code has a nasty handle leak.  Check this answer for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4306984/17034

Comment: @HansPassant--You are correct.  Should I take this answer down?  I don't want to cite your *more* correct answer.  That credit belongs to you.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, write a real answer, one that isn't just a set of links.

Comment: Thanks alot:):) but i even wanted to resize the image as a mouse pointer dynamically.... may i get any directions in this regaed?

Comment: Sorry, i meant, i want to resize the image used as a mouse pointer..:(

Comment: @HansPassant--Cool.  Will do.  Just didn't want to poach *your* ip ;).  Thanks.