# Custom Cursor All Black, no color

Tags: c#, colors

I select a Custom .cur file for my program like this:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (Stream resStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("Pie_X.hand.cur"))
{
  HandCursor = new Cursor(resStream);
  resStream.Close();
}
Canvas.Cursor = HandCursor;
```

I have checked it in the Resource Editor and it is in full color, but in the program it appears all black.
How can I fix this so that it appears in color?

Comment: Maybe you are using an invalid format. What dimensions and color depth does the cursor have?

Comment: 64x64, 24 bit. Thats all it says

Comment: Compare every property that the original HandCursor with the ones of the new cursor, and see where the difference might be significant.

Comment: I don't have another hand.cur to compare it to though, and I have no idea where to look.

Comment: Look at the default HandCursor?

Comment: But the original is black and white anyway, this cursor is meant to be colored but only black and white appear.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't naturally support colored cursors. Try some variation of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305800/using-custom-colored-cursors-in-a-c-sharp-windows-application) answer.

Comment: Can you post the actual cursor file?

Comment: I used that answer you posted, I just created the cursor files in appdata rather than embedding them.

Comment: There, added a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for future readers, I think it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306984/7197632

In particular, the opening paragraph of this answer says:

> The Cursor class is rather poorly done. For some mysterious reason it uses a legacy COM interface (IPicture), that interface doesn't support colored and animated cursors.

That would explain why the cursor appears all-black or all-white. I experienced this problem today myself.